# Windows 10 Start menu, notification center, not working after trying all available fixes

Tags: windows-10, start-menu, windows-10-v1511

I have a windows 10 pro (upgraded from windows 7), version 1511, build 10586.420 up to date. No virus, or malware found.

I have tried all the fixes from the following post without success.

[Windows 10 Start menu, notification center, store apps not working](https://superuser.com/questions/950680/windows-10-start-menu-notification-center-store-apps-not-working)

Found this on event viewer

```
   ShellExperienceHost.exe 
   10.0.10586.306 
   571afaa5 
   Windows.UI.Xaml.dll 
   10.0.10586.306 
   571af9f6 
   c000027b 
   0000000000596f88 
   1f9c 
   01d1c714b1136d4a 
   C:\Windows\SystemApps\ShellExperienceHost_cw5n1h2txyewy\ShellExperienceHost.exe 
   C:\Windows\System32\Windows.UI.Xaml.dll 
   db3bfc64-6301-455f-94c2-efed963be757 
   Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost_10.0.10586.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy 
   App
```

Dump file 1 [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xo9nw8l86s83m7h/ShellExperienceHost.exe.8816.rar?dl=0)

Dump file 2 [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/i2k0av030e3txlj/ShellExperienceHost.exe.5704.rar?dl=0)

Any other idea?

Comment: create a crash dump: pastebin.com/tU3Agf5M and share the compressed dmp file.

Comment: I have added the dump file to the question. It is the last one. I'm uploading 3 previous dump files in case you need them. Tx

Comment: ok, I posted an answer

Comment: Are you using EFS? My start menu broke after Encrypting the AppData folder under C:\users\username

Comment: No.. I was not..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the dump, your Windows has an issue to read data from the pagefile (`ERROR_SWAPERROR - Error performing inpage operation`).

```
Stowed Exception Array @ 0x000001e96112a7f0

Stowed Exception #1 @ 0x000001e961182c90
    0x800703E7 (FACILITY_WIN32 - Win32 Undecorated Error Codes): Error performing inpage operation.

    Stack    : 0x1e961191fe8
        7ff8d1435c02 Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::FrameworkApplication::MainASTAInitialize+0x12a
        7ff8d1435823 Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::FrameworkView::Initialize+0x73
        7ff8e81b98e8 twinapi_appcore!Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplicationView::CreateAndInitializeFrameworkView+0xb8
        7ff8e81d4e0a twinapi_appcore!Microsoft::WRL::RuntimeClass<Microsoft::WRL::RuntimeClassFlags<2>,Windows::Foundation::IEventHandler<Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::UnhandledErrorDetectedEventArgs * __ptr64>,Microsoft::WRL::FtmBase,Microsoft::WRL::Details::Nil,Microsoft::WRL::Details::Nil,Microsoft::WRL::Details::Nil,Microsoft::WRL::Details::Nil,Microsoft::WRL::Details::Nil,Microsoft::WRL::Details::Nil,Microsoft::WRL::Details::Nil>::RuntimeClass<Microsoft::WRL::RuntimeClassFlags<2>,Windows::Foundation::IEventHandler<Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::UnhandledErrorDetectedEventArgs * __ptr64>,Microsoft::WRL::FtmBase,Microsoft::WRL::Details::Nil,Microsoft::WRL::Details::Nil,Microsoft::WRL::Details::Nil,Microsoft::WRL::Details::Nil,Microsoft::WRL::Details::Nil,Microsoft::WRL::Details::Nil,Microsoft::WRL::Details::Nil>+0x1a6
        7ff8e98b9137 SHCore!??$MakeAndInitialize@VCClosableStreamWrapper@@UIStream@@PEAU2@$$T@Details@WRL@Microsoft@@YAJPEAPEAUIStream@@$$QEAPEAU3@$$QEA$$T@Z+0x27b
        7ff8eaa48102 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x22
        7ff8ed19c5b4 ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x34
```

Check your HDD for errors (SMART values with tools like [CrystalDiskInfo](http://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalDiskInfo/index-e.html), if they are fine, run `chkdsk /r /f` to detect and repair NTFS file system issues).

Comment: Tx,, for your answer, I executed chkdsk as you suggested, and some low level hard disk tool to repair bad sectors. The hard disk seems to be fine now. But I have no start menu yet. I edited the question to include the last dump file.

Comment: this time you get 0x800700C1 which is "no valid Win32 app". Run DISM commands to repair damaged windows files. But if your HDD shows bad sectors you should replace it asap.

Comment: You rock sir. After did a DISM and a SFC /scannow, I restarted my computer and the start menu, notification center, etc returned ! You're awesome, thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome. But you should still consider to replace the HDD if it has bad sectors.