# Windows 10 start menu, notification bar and native apps not working

Tags: windows-10, start-menu, notification-area

I am running Windows 10 Home edition and I installed update KB 3199986. After installing the update the start menu and the notification bar stopped working. Also I was unable to open any Windows 10 native apps like movies and TV, groove music and windows store. I assumed it was a bug in the update and thought that the next update would fix that work.

I recently installed update  KB 3200970 and the problem still persists. Even though the start menu is not working properly the docked  icons are working properly.

**Possible causes **

I have recently been seeing activate your Windows notification when I start up the computer even though my Windows 10 Home edition is activated. Also my time is not synchronising properly.

**Tried these solutions **

[Solution](https://superuser.com/questions/950680/windows-10-start-menu-notification-center-store-apps-not-working)

The solution suggests me to create a new user profile and check if the start menu is working in that profile. I tried creating a new profile and my start menu is also not working in that new one. I also tried the various commands suggested in that solution but none of them solved my problem.

How can I solve this problem ???

Answer (score 0):

1. Login to your current profile
2. Press <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, and select "Command Prompt (Admin)"
3. Enter the following commands, in this order:

   1. `net user "TempAdmin1" "password1" /add`
   2. `net user "TempAdmin2" "password2" /add`
   3. `net localgroup administrators "TempAdmin2" /add`
4. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd>, click Sign Out
5. Login to the "TempAdmin1" account using password "password1"
6. Logout, and then login to the "TempAdmin2" account, using "password2" (note: you must fully sign out, not just switch users)
7. Open File Explorer, select View, then check the box marked "Hidden Items"
8. Navigate to C:\Users\TempAdmin1\Local\TileDataLayer (click "continue" to gain access when prompted)
9. Right Click the folder "Database" & Copy
10. Now, navigate to the same folder for your damaged profile (C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\Local\TileDataLayer)
11. Right click "Database", and rename to "Database.BAD"
12. Right click empty area in the folder, and select Paste
13. Reboot, then sign back in with your original profile.

Now, assuming all is well, you want to delete the 2 accounts you created:

1. <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> -> Control Panel -> User Accounts -> Manage Another Account
2. Select Account, then "Delete Account"

Hope that helps!

Credits/Source: http://forums.windowscentral.com/windows-10-insider-preview/337063-5.htm#post3211209