# Start menu (and others) not working (v1709 and above, for Tile Store, NOT Tile Data Layer)

Tags: windows-10, start-menu, windows-10-v1709, windows-10-v1809

Some background:

At one point all Windows "Modern UI"-style apps stopped working, ie. the calculator, "Clocks & Alarms", etc.

Upon rebooting (to see if it would fix the issue), the start menu does not come up, and neither does the clock pop-up from the taskbar or the action center (on <kbd>Win + A</kbd>). Sound, Battery, Internet icons on the right side of the taskbar (what is that called?) also do not work.

Right click functionality still works for all of these, except for shortcuts on the left (annoying), and the action center which I can't reach without the keyboard shortcut (not an issue)

Windows settings still come up with <kbd>Win + I</kbd> and I can still access the control panel via the Run dialog  (<kbd>Win + R</kbd>, type in `control panel`)

---

Attempting to follow [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/972658/1112896),  made me run into two issues:

1. Upon logging into the temporary accounts, after waiting through Windows' """loading""" screen, I get the [black screen of death](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/black-screen-of-death+windows-10) (still not entirely sure how to deal with that)
2. Looking for `C:\Users\(any user)\AppData\Local\TileDataLayer` came up empty - the folder isn't there.

The TileDataLayer folder isn't there because [Tile Data Layer got deprecated in v1709 in favor of "Tile Store"](https://superuser.com/a/972658/1112896). I have v1809 b17763.864 (10 Home)

Therefore, that answer no longer applies. How can I reset or repair the Tile Store, or otherwise fix the Start menu and the rest of the nonfunctional UI?

(**Edit**) - Updating to 1909 fixed the issue. It could be that either the update process or the new version itself fixes this issue. Refer to the comments below.

Comment: What version of Windows 10 are you currently running?  v1709 (if so, it's 2+ yrs old and I believe outside of Microsoft's support window)?  Does this exist on v1903 / v1909?  If not, it sounds like a bug that got fixed and would be recommended to update to the most current version of Win10. Have you tried running **`DISM`** and **`SFC`**, _in that order_? `dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth`, reboot, then `sfc /scannow`, reboot.

Comment: Just remembered to add the version to the question, it's 1809. I've ran both those commands already (other answers to this issue mention them) and rebooted with no noticeable improvement.

Comment: Checking Windows Update under Settings, and apparently I have the option to update to 1909..? I'm worried this might invalidate my question though.

Also, I can't remember what order I ran DISM and SFC in, so I'll try them again in the order you mentioned.

Comment: There's not a lot of documentation that comes up for this specific issue when using a search engine, and the best I came across was [this](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/678494/start-menu-corruption-tile-database-is-corrupt/).  A lot of users don't know `DISM` should be ran before `SFC`, as `DISM` verifies the system file backups in `%WinDir%\WinSxS` against Windows Update's known good copies, whereas `SFC` uses those backups in `%WinDir%\WinSxS` to compare system files in `%WinDir%` against.  If you want an answer before updating to v1909, I would also ask on the Spiceworks Forum.

Comment: Ran DISM, rebooted, ran SFC, and it reported having fixed some files. Rebooted again and the start menu still doesn't come up.

I don't really have a reason not to update, I would have after fixing this anyways, so I'll update to 1909.

Comment: If the update doesn't fix the issue, and this still doesn't have an answer from anyone, I would definitely post the question on the [Spiceworks Forum](https://community.spiceworks.com/), as a majority of the members work in IT and Microsoft has dedicated [vendor] personnel who monitor the forum for questions pertaining to Windows

Comment: Updating fixed the issue. I don't think that's a good enough answer to this question, so I'll leave it open. Thank you for the time you spent on this @JW0914